# Pass value from a component to the parent instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

I have a component named `cartComponent` with a data property `cartCount` that gets incremented whenever a new item is added to the cart.

I need to use that value to update the value in the template which is not a part of the component. Is this possible?

Here's is the script for my parent Vue instance:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#cart-app",
  components: {
    cart: cartComponent
  },
  data: {
    searchQuery: '',
    appliedFilters: ['Day 1'],
    purchaseData: json,
    cCount: 0 // CARTCOUNT; NEEDS TO BE UPDATED FROM COMPONENT
  }
});
```

Comment: I've added an answer, but I might be misinterpreting your question. Are you passing `cCount` as a prop to the `cart` component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the ideal case for using the [`.sync` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier).

From the documentation:

> When a child component mutates a prop that has .sync, the value change will be reflected in the parent

---

In your case, you could add the `.sync` modifier to the `cCount` property being bound in the template (assuming that your component has a `cCount` property):

```
<cart :c-count.sync="cCount"></cart>
```

And in the script for the cart component emit an `update:cCount` event when the count is incremented:

```
methods: {
  incrementCount() {
    this.cartCount++;
    this.$emit('update:cCount', this.cartCount);
  }
}
```

This will automatically set the value of the parent Vue instance's `cCount` property to the value of the cart component's `cartCount` property.

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/54vzd3tz/)

---

This feature is available starting in Vue version 2.3.0, but if you are using an earlier version, this would give you the same functionality:

```
<cart :c-count="cCount" @update:foo="val => cCount = val"></cart>
```

This is because `<comp :foo.sync="bar"></comp>` is just syntactic sugar for:

```
<comp :foo="bar" @update:foo="val => bar = val"></comp>
```